# How to add a arguments to subcommand in makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to let users execute following command:

```
make generate sub-command arg1 arg2
```

- generate is a fixed command.
- sub-command could be json, yaml and could be extended in the future.
- arg1, arg2 are not optional (lets assume simple strings)

how can I create a `makefile` for this?

Comment: You can't.  All non-option arguments to make are considered targets to be built.  Make is not a generic language interpreter like shell or Python or Perl or whatever.  It's a specific tool to do specific things and that's all it does.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to work within make's syntax, which isn't as flexible as a regular script or CLI program would be. The syntax you want wouldn't work because make would consider the arguments as additional targets to build. (It's possible you could finagle it into working. Even if you could, I wouldn't. As an end user familiar with make's syntax, I'd be confused by targets being arguments to other targets and not proper targets of their own.)

One idiomatic solution is to use variable assignments. For example:

```
make generate FORMAT=json PRETTY=yes
```

You could then access `$(FORMAT)`, `$(PRETTY)`, etc., inside the Makefile. It's a bit clunky but it'd work.

Comment: is it possible to get FORMAT as argument and set it in a target and then use that target in `make generate` target?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking about calling another target within the Makefile? You could do that with `$(MAKE) other-target`, and it would pass the variables along automatically. Or `$(MAKE) other-target FORMAT=other` to pass a different value for `$(FORMAT)`.

Comment: I think what you're trying to describe would be very bad practice.  The proper way to do it would be as @JohnKugelman described.   If you want a simpler syntax, you could write a bash script that takes the arguments as you imagine them, which then calls make with the proper variables set.